# How do we ignore the order of letters in calculating Levenshtein distance?

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, edit-distance

This question is not new and i have seen some form of explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828132/levenshtein-distance-how-to-better-handle-words-swapping-positions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675034/string-similarity-levenshtein-distance?rq=1). Both methods described performing N grams (bigrams mostly) calculations on the terms of query 1 and query 2 and then finding the cosine similarity.

I was hoping for a clarification based on what i understand:

I need to get the TF-IDF score for all bigrams in query 1 and query 2 and then use that score to calculate the cosine similarity score. 
If this is so, would anyone be able to kindly write a simple python code for clearer explanation?

Comment: So a histogram distance between histograms of bigrams of queries?

Comment: Maybe sort the inputs first?