# Group keys within a dictionary based on their similarity

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I would like to group keys in a dictionary based on their respective similarity. I want to look for similarity within different keys, and if they are similar enough, group them. Probably by using some sort of similarity score. I am thus specifically *not* interested in how they values within those dictionary match up (in the example below I kept them the same). I have been looking at similarity scores using sklearn cosine_similarity, but I could not find a way to apply this to keys in a dictionary. Anyone any clues on this?

I made a test dictionary to show what I mean. Some keys are very similar, and I would like to group those. How to group those is beyond the point now, but let's say I would like to add the numbers up.

As always, many thanks!

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

dictionary = {'United States': {'population': 350, 'Continent': 'North America'},
              'united states': {'population': 350, 'Continent': 'North America'},
              'the United States of America': {'population': 350, 'Continent': 'North America'},
              'USA': {'population': 350, 'Continent': 'North America'},
              'Netherlands': {'population': 17, 'Continent': 'Europe'},
              'the Netherlands': {'population': 17, 'Continent': 'Europe'},
              'Japan': {'population': 160, 'Continent': 'Japan'}
              }
```

Comment: @BuddyBob edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't calculate cosine similarity between strings. You can either calculate the pairwise string distance and cluster on that or using [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf) on character n-grams, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828132/levenshtein-distance-how-to-better-handle-words-swapping-positions) for a similar discussion. In your case, we can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb',ngram_range=(2,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary).transpose()
mat = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df.index)
cl = AgglomerativeClustering(4).fit(cosine_similarity(mat))
df['label'] = cl.labels_

                             population      Continent  label
United States                       350  North America      0
united states                       350  North America      0
the United States of America        350  North America      0
USA                                 350  North America      3
Netherlands                          17         Europe      2
the Netherlands                      17         Europe      2
Japan                               160          Japan      1
```

I think it's not so easy to group `USA` and other `United States` together.

Comment: I was just starting looking into this direction. This is a great example of how this can be done, so thanks! Btw, I don't really like that you have to define the amount of groups you will split the data into. I created this example as a simplification, but I'm actually doing this for a string dataset of >2000 strings.

Comment: I also read a lot about the FuzzyWuzzy python library. Anyone any clues on how @StupidWolf's example compares to this, pro's and con's etc?

Comment: @CrossLord, you can also cut the tree at a certain height https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree.html . And it all depends on how similar your strings are, for fuzzywuzzy or any distance based approaches, you have to account for the pairwise calculations